# Adding long numbers gives me minus result?

Tags: c++

when i try to add two long numbers it gives me minus result :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
 int a=1825228665;
 int b=1452556585;
 cout<<a+b;
 return 0;
}
```

This gives me:

```
-1017182046
```

Comment: Have you tried using `unsigned int` instead?

Comment: integer overflow, you exceed the max value for integer (specific to your compiler/os)

Comment: integer constant is too large for "long" type

Comment: That's an overflow error. The result of the addition is too big to fit in a `int` variable. Even with an `unsigned int` you'd still get garbage. You should use a larger type, eg `long` or `long long`.

Comment: The sum simply too much to be stored as integer.

Comment: then what should i do?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos An unsigned integer will work fine. The result is approximately 3.2 billion, well within the range of an unsigned 32-bit integer.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't thing the question has to do with the specific values. `int`s are small and it's easy to get an overflow error. Besides, `int` isn't guaranteed to be 32 bit. The standard specifies minimum sizes: 16-bit for int, 32-bit for long

Comment: 4294967295 > 3650457330

Comment: When i try to add ULL to the number it work well , but i want to identify the variable a as ULL even if it doesn't equal a known value

Comment: You don't need a 64 bit int for this....but you can declare an `unsigned long long int` on some systems

Comment: Try `cout<<(unsigned int)(a+b);`

Comment: @DavidWilkins i'm not talking specifically about this numbers , when i try to write unsigned long long int a it don't work !

Comment: This has devolved into a discussion and is no longer an answerable question

Answer (score 0):

It's overflowing of the type. When you add two big number that the result can't be stored in chosen type it get overfloved. In most cases it will wraped the number, but it's not defined in the standard. So in some compilers the result is undefined.

For int and other numeric types when program can't store this big number in it we can see a overflow of it.

Lets say that int can store number from -10 to 10, when you do this:

```
int a = 10;
int b = a+1;
```

You will get -10 in `b` or some random value (it can be anything because the result is undefined)

Comment: I tried its giving 11.

Comment: Re your first statement: when an arithmetic operation results in a value which can't be represented in the type, the behavior is undefined.  Most implementations do wrap, but it's not at all required.

Comment: Ok James Kanze,thanks. You're right

Comment: @Himanshu That's because your `int` can probably store more than just `[-10, 10]`.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the results overflows. Since the first bit in numeric signed data types is used for the sign representation. The specific representation is called Two's complement ([Wikipedia article here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)). Practically a 1 in this bit maps to a - while a 0 to +. The solution to this problem is using a larger data type like long. Larger it means that the memory used to store it is bigger so the range of values increases.

Comment: i used long but didn't work too , how can i declare a variable as ULL ? I tried unsigned long long int a but it didn't work.

Comment: Ask that as a different question please